# strange console.log behaviour

Tags: ecmascript-6, google-chrome-devtools, console.log

Im feelin a bit stupid to ask this question

```
"use strict";

console.log("youhou");

var countdown = void 0;
function timer(secondes) {

  var now = Date.now();
  var then = now + secondes * 1000;

 console.log({ now: now, then: then });
 }
```

but when I check all those console.logs on the google developement tool * the first one does not pop up  and say  "youhou" to confirm it works

then when i write timer(10)in the GDT* it says

```
VM892:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: timer is not defined
at <anonymous>:1:13
```

my function is clearly defined I am confused  I don't understand ? 
 plus  in codpen everything works just fine

can some one help ?

Comment: I run you code on the console I didn't get any error

Comment: yes, it works fine.

Comment: I didn't get the error. Check without 'use strict' or open on new tab so that console doesn't have cache from code you entered

Comment: Sounds like you're a victim of the broken console filtering in new Chrome, see https://crbug.com/717776 and [Is there a fix for the latest Chrome Dev Tools blunder](//stackoverflow.com/q/43747946)